# Vertex coordinates in pixel cordinates

Tags: direct3d

By default

> Direct3D assumes that the viewport clipping volume ranges from -1.0 to 1.0 in X, and from 1.0 to -1.0 in Y.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/direct3d9/viewports-and-clipping

I'm just wanting to do 2D rendering, and I'd like to provide vertex buffer data such that the *top left of a pixel is a an integral coordinate* i.e. the centres of pixels are at `(*.5, *.5)`

[image]

That is for a viewport size of 1280x720 I'd like the X to range from 0 to 1280 and Y to range from 0 to 720.

Currently the hello triangle sample gives the coordinates as

```
Vertex triangleVertices[] =
{
    { { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f }, color1 },
    { { 0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f }, color2 },
    { { -0.25f, -0.25f, 0.0f }, color3 }
};
```

What changes are necessary get the same result while providing the following coordinates

```
Vertex triangleVertices[] =
{
    { { width/2 + 0.00f * width/2, height/2 + 0.25f * height/2, 0.0f }, color1 },
    { { width/2 + 0.25f * width/2, height/2 - 0.25f * height/2, 0.0f }, color2 },
    { { width/2 - 0.25f * width/2, height/2 - 0.25f * height/2, 0.0f }, color3 }
};
```

Here's how they did it in Direct3D 9 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/the-direct3d-transformation-pipeline but it seems like things have changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2D rendering, you just need to use an orthographic projection that is based on the screen pixel dimensions.

```
Matrix proj = Matrix::CreateScale( 2.f/float(backBufferWidth),
   -2.f/float(backBufferHeight), 1.f)
   * Matrix::CreateTranslation( -1.f, 1.f, 0.f );
```

or

```
Matrix proj = Matrix::CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
    0.f, float(backBufferWidth), float(backBufferHeight), 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
```

or using [DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) instead of the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper:

```
XMMATRIX proj = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterRH(
    0.f, float(backBufferWidth), float(backBufferHeight), 0.f, 0.f, 1.f));

// Use XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH for a left-handed projection instead of right-handed.
// Which of course largely doesn't matter for 2D rendering without
// a z-buffer.
```

Then you use that projection in a standard vertex shader with a transformation matrix:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register( b0 )
{
    matrix Projection;
}

float4 main( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
    float4 Pos = mul( Pos, Projection );
    return Pos;
}
```

See *DirectX Tool Kit* `SpriteBatch` on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the viewport is fixed in Direct3D 11/12 to be `[-1,1]x[-1,1]` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-rasterizer-stage-getting-started

I imagine the thing to do is write a vertex shader to transform `[0,1280]x[0,720]` -> `[-1,1]x[-1,1]`. I guess a possible strategy is to always having a square viewport and then use a scissor rect for clipping.

You can see, in this spinning cube sample, how constant buffers are used to provide the transform matrixes to the vertex shader https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/main/Direct3D11Tutorials/Tutorial04/Tutorial04.fxh